# How to use free online servers like python anywhere to run python script at the same time every day?

Tags: python, selenium, server, automation, cloud

I got the idea from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fQjA8w1woQ) but I realized the script I made involves selenium and the chrome driver required for selenium. I need to run the script around midnight everyday. How do I work around this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
from selenium import webdriver
import datetime

PATH = "C:/Users/abhin/Downloads/Selenium drivers/chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('XXXXX')

user = "XXXXX"
password = "XXXXX"
number = "XXXXX"
purpose = "XXXXX"
dep = "XXXXX"

today = datetime.date.today()
bkDate = today
bkDate_new = bkDate.strftime("%a, %d-%m-%Y")
bkDateNum = bkDate.strftime("%d")

user_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("j_username")
user_textbox.send_keys(user)

password_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("j_password")
password_textbox.send_keys(password)

login_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.form-button")
login_button.click()

driver.get("https://XXXXX")

number_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("contact_no")
number_textbox.send_keys(number)

purpose_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("purpose")
purpose_textbox.send_keys(purpose)

slot1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/main/div[1]/fieldset/form/div[8]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/label[1]")
slot1.click()

submit_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/main/div[1]/fieldset/form/div[10]/div[2]/div/i/input")
submit_btn.click()
```

Comment: Since you are using windows you can use windows task scheduler to run the scripts whenever you want. Create windows batch file and add that in task scheduler.

Comment: Yeah but then I'd have to leave me laptop on all the time so I'd prefer another option

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to run the script from your PC, you can buy a raspberry pi and let it do this job for your (by making creating a shell script to schedule script running), or you can opt-in to host your script in cloud, but you will need to pay more than if you would use a personal device.