# How do I get my Python Script to work on the cloud?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, cloud, pythonanywhere

I've successfully created a script to automatically book for a slot in my gym regularly using python and selenium. It works fine but I'd like to find a way to get it to work without having my laptop on 24/7. I was looking at using pythonanywhere but it doesn't seem to work with scripts with selenium. Is there workaround? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
from selenium import webdriver
import datetime

PATH = "C:/Users/abhin/Downloads/Selenium drivers/chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('XXXXX')

user = "XXXXX"
password = "XXXXX"
number = "XXXXX"
purpose = "XXXXX"
dep = "XXXXX"

today = datetime.date.today()
bkDate = today
bkDate_new = bkDate.strftime("%a, %d-%m-%Y")
bkDateNum = bkDate.strftime("%d")

user_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("j_username")
user_textbox.send_keys(user)

password_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("j_password")
password_textbox.send_keys(password)

login_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.form-button")
login_button.click()

driver.get("https://XXXXX")

number_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("contact_no")
number_textbox.send_keys(number)

purpose_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id("purpose")
purpose_textbox.send_keys(purpose)

slot1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/main/div[1]/fieldset/form/div[8]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/label[1]")
slot1.click()

submit_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/main/div[1]/fieldset/form/div[10]/div[2]/div/i/input")
submit_btn.click()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use free online servers like python anywhere to run python script at the same time every day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64214642/how-to-use-free-online-servers-like-python-anywhere-to-run-python-script-at-the)

Comment: That's actually my previous question but I didn't get any answers for it lol

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run it on PythonAnywhere you should use [Scheduled tasks feature](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/ScheduledTasks/) -- after adjusting the script to work there (e.g. changing the PATH variable which points to your local chromedriver). In order to make selenium working you need to contact support@pythonanywhere.com and ask for enabling beta features for that.

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your question is that you are looking for some free hosting platform where you can deploy your script.
here are some free hosting platform please have a look.
https://www.wpbeginner.com/showcase/best-free-website-hosting-compared/